# Is it possible for the pass utility to use symmetric encryption for a specific directory?

Tags: encryption, passwords, gnupg

Recently, I've been looking into using the Unix tool `pass` as my password manager. I've figured out a workflow I'm happy with for handling my passwords and personal info. Now I'm looking into the best way to handle my 2FA QR codes, backup codes, etc.

Obviously, passwords and 2FA details shouldn't be encrypted with the same key. So I was wondering if there was a way to let `pass` know that anything under a specific directory should be encrypted symmetrically. From what I can gather, the use of a `.gpg-id` file in any directory managed by `pass` lets the app know that it should encrypt the files using the keys listed in the file. However, it's not clear to me if there's a way to instruct pass to encrypt the files symmetrically. This is probably something that can be handled manually, although it would be tedious and error-prone. Is anyone aware if this is possible? Is it a bad idea? Should I generate a dummy key instead that's encrypted with the passphrase that I'd be using to encrypt symmetrically anyway? Or is this something a subkey could be used for?

Comment: Why not go with a password manager, like KeePass, LastPass, etc? Or TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt/LUKS?

Comment: I enjoy `pass`'s simplicity and I enjoy its CLI. That's all there is to it really.

Comment: Lastpass is what I used for most stuff. I'm not happy putting banking credentials in it. Keepass version updates weren't compatible with an old version.. which was a bit of a pain.

Comment: I implemented one of these https://github.com/talwrii/sympass . There may well be others lurking on github.